# Axes/Frame Label as Log base 10

Tags: plotting

I am trying to label one of the frames on a ListPlot as log_10(x).  When I try `ListPlot[twodimndata,Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style[Log10[r], 20], Style[d, 20]}}` the output on the x-axis is `Log[r]/Log[10]`, rather than Log_10[r] as I expected

How can I get Mathematica to plot Log_10[r] on the x-axis?

Comment: `LogPlot`? Its under LogPlot in Mathematica help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `HoldForm[]` to prevent the automatic evaluation of `Log10[r]`:

```
data = SortBy[Transpose[{Log[RandomReal[{1, 10^5}, 6]], RandomReal[1, 6]}], First];

ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style[HoldForm[Log10[r]], 20], Style[d, 20]},
         Joined -> True]
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Comment: On the other hand, you might be interested in the function `ListLogLinearPlot[]`...

Comment: Yeah, I gave `ListLogLinearPlot` a go originally, but the numbers on the frame were cluttered, so I thought I would try the other way to see how it looked.